# Can I disable interpolation (enable nearest-neighbor filtering/upsampling) with \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, png

[image: Bad] [image: Good]

When I include the .png image on the right side (32x30 px) in a LaTeX document and typeset it with latexpdf I get the blurry result on the left, even if I turn interpolation off using `[interpolate=false]`. Can I do anything about that (apart from upsampling the image to 600 dpi with nearest-neighbor filtering beforehand)?

**Update:**

As explained in the linked question, it’s an issue with PDF viewers.  I ended up using nearest-neighbor upsampling with imagemagicks `for f in *.png; do convert $f -filter point -resize 2000% _$f; done` to make sure it looks correct in all cases.  (I calculated the resizing factor so that it scales the picture to 600 dpi.)